# Error server Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to write a React web app, but I received an error.  I can't understand why it doesn't work.
When a user enter in my web app, I want to save his email address in a Redux store.

types.js

```
export const LOGIN = 'LOGIN';
export const DATA = 'DATA';
```

Here I defined the type of my actions

searchActions.js

```
import {LOGIN, DATA} from './types';
import axios from 'axios';
import store from '../store'

export const login  = ()=> {
    store.dispatch({
        type: LOGIN
    })
};

export const information = async(email)  => {
    store.dispatch({
        type: DATA,
        payload: email
    })
}
```

Here wrote what my actions have to do according to the type.

userReducer.js

```
import {LOGIN, DATA} from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
   isLogged: false,
   email: '',
}

export default function(state = initialState, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case LOGIN:
            return {
                ...state,
                isLogged: true
            };
        case DATA:
            return {
                ...state,
                email: action.payload
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

This is a simple form. If the response from the database is positive I  want to save his mail in the store. If I delete the 41st line it works well.
SignIn.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import {login, information} from '../actions/searchActions';

import './component.css'
import axios from 'axios';
const baseUrl = "http://localhost:3000";

class SignIn extends Component {
    state = { 
        email:'',
        password: '',
    }
    render() {

        const handleChange = (e) => {
            this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value});
        }

        const handleSubmit = (e) => {
            //aggiungere la validazione del form in una futura versione
            e.preventDefault();
            access();
        }

        const access = () => {
            const url = baseUrl + '/router/sign-in';
            axios.get(url, {
                params: {
                    email: this.state.email,
                    password: this.state.password
                }
            })
            .then(res=>{
              if (res.data.status !== undefined) {
                const data = res.data.status
                console.log(JSON.stringify(data)) //users entrato
                login();
                this.props.history.push('/')
                this.props.information(this.state.email) // HERE IS THE ERROR.
// if I delate this line it works

            }
            else {
                alert(res.data.error)
            }
        })
        .catch(error=>{
            alert("Error server "+ error)
        })
    }


        return ( 
            <div className="firstly-square">
                <div className="center-form">
                    <form action="" className="sign" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                        <div className="title-sign">
                            SignIn
                        </div>
                        <div className="signin-username">
                            <label htmlFor="email" className="signin-label">email</label>
                            <input type="text" name="email" className="signin-input" onChange={handleChange} value={this.state.email}/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="signin-password">
                            <label htmlFor="password" className="signin-label">password</label>
                            <input type="password" name="password" className="signin-input" onChange={handleChange}/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="signin-bottone">
                            <button type="submit" className="signin-button">Sumbit</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
         );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    email : state.user.email
  });

  export default connect( mapStateToProps, { information })(SignIn);
```

Please, help me.
Thanks

Comment: Are you using any middleware for async actions? check https://redux.js.org/advanced/async-actions

Comment: You need to configure middleware redux-thunk in your configure store to use dispatch

Answer (score 0):

This is my store.js

```
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import {composeWithDevTools} from 'redux-devtools-extension';

import rootReducer from './reducers'

const middleware = [thunk];
const initialState = {};

const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware)));


export default store;
```